# Asymptotic behavior of $\int_0^1 \text{min}\{1,x^{-d}(1-x^d)^n\} dx$ as $n\to\infty$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am trying to find bounds on

\begin{equation*}
\int_0^1 \text{min}\{1,x^{-d}(1-x^d)^n\} dx~\text{as}~n\to\infty,~d\in\mathbb{N}. 
\end{equation*}

I found this integral trying to bound some probability, therefore, I have no hope for a closed form and I am only interested in the behavior as $n\to\infty$, for fixed $d\in\mathbb{N}$.

Unfortunately, I can't even get rid of the minimum myself.

Comment: Are you sure you want that first exponent to be negative? It means your function will always be 1 when $x$ is close to 0 and that strikes me as a little odd.

Comment: @Neal Looks good to me. The $\min$ is to cut off the non-integrable singularity of $x^{-d}$ at $0$. If the first exponent were non-negative, we'd end up with a beta function integral.

Comment: @DanielFischer OK, that makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to estimate our integral, we just need to find in which point $x\in(0,1)$ we have:
$$ (1-x)^n = x. \tag{1}$$
By exploting convexity, we may use Newton's method with starting point in the origin to prove that the solution of $(1)$ is greater than $\frac{1}{n+1}$. That gives that our integral is trivially $\geq\frac{1}{(n+1)^{1/d}}$.

On the other hand,
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\min\left(1,x^{-d}(1-x^d)^n\right)\,dx\leq\frac{1}{(n+1)^{1/d}}+\int_{(n+1)^{-1/d}}^{1}x^{-d}(1-x^d)^n\,dx\tag{2} $$
and:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\int_{(n+1)^{-1/d}}^{1}x^{-d}(1-x^d)^n\,dx&=&\frac{1}{d}\int_{\frac{1}{n+1}}^{1}y^{1/d-2}(1-y)^n\,dy\\&\leq&\frac{1}{d}\int_{\frac{1}{n+1}}^{+\infty}y^{1/d-2}e^{-ny}\,dy\\&\leq&\frac{e\,(n+1)^{1/d}}{(3d-1)(n+1)^3}\tag{3}\end{eqnarray*}$$
by estimating the last integral with minus the inverse of the derivative of the integrand function in the left endpoint. So we have that the original integral is not very far from being $\frac{1}{(n+1)^{1/d}}$.

Comment: @ Jack D'Aurizio : Numerical calculations do not confirm that. See the case $d=5, n=150$ [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u8245f2y55n17xc/plot.pdf?dl=0).

Comment: @user64494: you are right, something has to be fixed in the upper bound. Anyway, the first lines gives the general principle: the estimate our integral, we just need to provide an approximation for the solution of $(1)$, and the integral should be $\frac{C}{n^{1/d}}$ plus a small error.

Comment: @ Jack D'Aurizio: I think the integrall under consideration approaches $\frac 1 2$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @user64494: then compute the integral with $d=2$ and a big $n$ and you will see that you are well below $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @ Jack D'Aurizio: Yes, indeed. However, numerical calculations suggest that the one does not tend to zero as $n$ approaches infinity.

Comment: @user64494: I disagree. Numerical simulations (with $d=2$) clearly show that. Obviously, with a greater $d$ there is a slower convergence towards zero.

Comment: @ Jack D'Aurizio: Can you present those? I obtain $0.202... $ for $d=2, n=100$, $0.12937... $ for $d=2, n=300$, and $0.10451... $ for $d=2, n=500.$

Comment: @user64494: and don't they appear to you to converge to zero like $\frac{C}{\sqrt{n}}$ as prevented?

Comment: D'Auruzio: No, those don't appear to be like $\frac{C}{\sqrt{n}}$ because of $ \frac {\ln(0.2020503966)} {100} =-0.1599238125e-1$, $\frac {\ln(0.1293711565)} {300} =-0.6816899413e-2 $, and $ \frac {\ln(0.1045135149)} {500}=-0.4516877774e-2$. These numbers are far away of $-0.5$ as you expect.

Comment: @user64494: I do not get what you are computing in such a way. If $a_n\approx\frac{C}{\sqrt{n}}$, then $\frac{\log a_n}{n}\sim -\frac{\log n}{n}.$

Comment: @ Jack S'Auruzio: Sorry. Then consider $\frac {\ln(0.2020503966)} {\ln(100)} =-.3472701465,\, \frac {\ln(0.1293711565)} {\ln(300)}=-.3585462511,$ and $ \frac {\ln(0.1045135149)} {\ln(500)}=-.3634080945$ which are far away of $-0.5$.

Comment: @user64494: not so much. The best way to prove that $a_n\approx\frac{C}{\sqrt{n}}$, anyway, is just to plot $a_n\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: @ Jack D'Aurizio : Could you kindly produce that, especially for $n>100$? I find it to be your duty.

Comment: @user64494: "duty"? Why? That was not requested by the OP.